# How to select only the best features by setting up the threshold using FSelector information gain in R language?

Tags: r, information-gain, fselector

I have done information gain feature selection in R by using FSelector package in R

```
install.packages("RWekajars")
install.packages("FSelector")
library(FSelector)

weights <- information.gain(Classname~., df)

Attributes                                          attr_importance
X.1                                              3.6349780
X                                                3.6349780
Value_1                                          3.7128973
Value_1                                          0.9652070
Item_1                                           2.0845525
```

Now, I need select best features out of this based on the **attr_importance**. How to select the best features in R based on the threshold values and how to set the threshold value?

Comment: `weights$Attributes[weights$attr_importance > threshold]`

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `cutoff.k` from the Package **FSelector** that solves your problem:

- cutoff.k chooses k best attributes
- cutoff.k.percent chooses best k * 100% of attributes
- cutoff.biggest.diff chooses a subset of attributes which are signiﬁcantly better than other.

Eg: `results <- cutoff.k.percent(weights, 0.9)` will return all Attributes until 0.9 is reached.
Or: `results <- cutoff.k(weights, 2)` will return the 2 Attributes with most information gain.
Dos this solve your problem?